# Drake Installation Freeze

Tags: drake

I am trying to install the python-binding of drake. After make --j it freezes. I believe I have done everything correctly for the previous steps. Can anyone help? I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.6.9.

Thank you in advance. It looks like this.

[Frozen Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gYuC.jpg)

Comment: It would help us if you showed the actual commands you used, rather than just saying you think that you did them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `make` (no `-j` flag) or `make -j1` because `bazel` (which is called internally during the build) handles the parallelism of the build (and of tests) and will set the number of jobs to the number of cores by default (appears to be 8 in your case).

To adjust the parallelism to reduce the number of jobs to less than the number of cores, create a file named `user.bazelrc` at the root of the repository (same level as the `WORKSPACE` file) with the content

```
test --jobs=N
```

for some `N` less than the number of cores that you have.

See also https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#bazelrc.

Answer (score 0):

From the screen shot, it doesn't look like the drake build system is doing anything wrong.  But `make -j` is probably trying to do too many things in parallel.   Try starting with `-j4` and if it still freezes, go down to `2`, etc.

Comment: Checking with Jamie S. on this one; not sure if job control will make it through to Bazel from CMake. @Steven Yeung, if Russ's solution does not work (it may!), you may want to make a change like this one and then re-run the CMake configuration: https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/drake/commit/980a2fe

Comment: Confirmed with Jamie that unfortunately job control for make will not make it through. Will see if I can PR a suggestion for controlling that, though! @Steven For the time being, you may need to use my hack.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly out of memory..

A hacky solution is to change the `CMakeLists.txt` file to set the max number of jobs bazel uses by adding `--jobs N` (where N is the number of jobs you allow concurrently) after `${BAZEL_TARGETS}` like so

```
ExternalProject_Add(drake_cxx_python
  SOURCE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND :
  BUILD_COMMAND
    ${BAZEL_ENV}
    "${Bazel_EXECUTABLE}"
    ${BAZEL_STARTUP_ARGS}
    build
    ${BAZEL_ARGS}
    ${BAZEL_TARGETS}
    --jobs 1
  BUILD_IN_SOURCE ON
  BUILD_ALWAYS ON
  INSTALL_COMMAND
    ${BAZEL_ENV}
    "${Bazel_EXECUTABLE}"
    ${BAZEL_STARTUP_ARGS}
    run
    ${BAZEL_ARGS}
    ${BAZEL_TARGETS}
    --
    ${BAZEL_TARGETS_ARGS}
  USES_TERMINAL_BUILD ON
  USES_TERMINAL_INSTALL ON
)
```